# xcode error: Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'UIApplication' when using Ionic 5

Tags: reactjs, swift5, ionic5, xcode12

I have a project written in Ionic 5 using React with TypeScript. A managed without a problem to build the Android app, but for iOS i get stuck. When I add iOS project with npx cap add iOS it creates the project. After opening it and start analyze the code I got an error that says:

Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'UIApplication'.

Here is the  whole code where I get the error:

```
import Foundation

@objc(CAPBackgroundTaskPlugin)
public class CAPBackgroundTaskPlugin : CAPPlugin {
  var tasks: [String:UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier] = [:]
  
  public override func load() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.onAppTerminate), name: .UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    // NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.onAppBackgrounded), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
  }
  
  @objc func beforeExit(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
    var taskId: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
    
    taskId = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask {
      UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskId)
        self.tasks[call.callbackId] = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
    }
    
    self.tasks[call.callbackId] = taskId
    call.success()
  }
  
  @objc func finish(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
    guard let callbackTaskId = call.getString("taskId") else {
      call.error("Must provide taskId returned from calling start()")
      return
    }
    
    guard let taskId = tasks[callbackTaskId] else {
      call.error("No such task found")
      return
    }
    
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(taskId)
  }

  
  @objc func fetch(_ call: CAPPluginCall) {
   
  }
  
  @objc func onAppTerminate() {
    CAPLog.print("APP TERMINATING IN BACKGROUND TASK")
  }
}
```

I am using macOS Catalina, Swift 5, xCode 12.x, React, Typescript.

tinny